# Finding Image and Place into another img source

Tags: jquery, html

My Html Markup is like this

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="slider">
        <img src=""/>
    </div> 
    <div class="clear slider"></div>

    <div class="slider ndslider">
        <a href="#" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="#" title=""/>
        </a>
    </div>    

    <div class="slider rdslider">
        <a href="" rel="bookmark">
            <img src="" title=""/>
        </a>
   </div>       
<div class="slider thslider nivoSlider">
    <a rel="bookmark" href="" class="nivo-imageLink" >
        <img src="image src" >
    </a>
    <a rel="bookmark" href="" class="nivo-imageLink">
        <img title="" src="">
    </a>
    <a rel="bookmark" href="#" class="nivo-imageLink">
        <img title="" src="">
    </a>
    <div class="nivo-slice"></div>
    <div class="nivo-slice"></div>
    <div class="nivo-slice"></div>
    <div class="nivo-directionNav">
        <a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a>
        <a class="nivo-nextNav">Next</a>
   </div>
   <div class="nivo-controlNav">
        <a rel="0" class="nivo-control active">
            <img alt="" src="undefined">
        </a>
        <a rel="1" class="nivo-control">
            <img alt="" src="undefined">
       </a>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

I want to find the all the images inside this DIV

```
<div class="slider thslider nivoSlider">

</div>
```

and set that images on to this

```
<div class="nivo-controlNav">
      <a rel="0" class="nivo-control active">
          <img alt="" src="undefined">
      </a>
</div>
```

For Doing the same i had written my custom jQuery but it is not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.thslider a img').each(function(){
            var imgSrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            var newSrc = 'http://saorabh-test1.rtcamp.info/wp-content/themes/twentyten/timthumb.php?src='+ imgSrc +' &h=50&w=50&zc=1';
            jQuery(".thslider .nivo-controlNav a img").attr('src',newSrc);

        });
    });
```

Help me..

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What happens if you do test outputs in your loop, e.g. alert() the element's ID? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

Ok here is the problem .. your original url contained the entire path to the image, so the src you retrieved was a complete path and not the src attribute you were passing in the URL as a parameter..

Change your code to this and it should be fine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.thslider a img').each(function(index){
           var imgSrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
           // now we replace the dimensions from the original url using regular expressions.. the 50 is the new dimensions .. change it appropriately..
           var newSrc = imgSrc.replace(/h=(.*?)&/gi,'h=50&').replace(/w=(.*?)&/gi,'w=50&');

           jQuery(".thslider .nivo-controlNav a:eq("+index+") img").attr('src',newSrc);
       });
   });
```

---

***Original answer***

What exactly is not working ?

If the problem is that all the destination images get changed to the same thing then change your code to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('.thslider a img').each(function(index){
            var imgSrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            var newSrc = 'http://saorabh-test1.rtcamp.info/wp-content/themes/twentyten/timthumb.php?src='+ imgSrc +' &h=50&w=50&zc=1';
            jQuery(".thslider .nivo-controlNav a:eq("+index+") img").attr('src',newSrc);

        });
    });
```

Comment: I am able to find the image but not able to append it in the other div img src..what i get the image src..

var imgSrc = jQuery(this).attr('src');
this variable returs what i want but simply if i use this 
 jQuery(".thslider .nivo-controlNav a img").attr('src',imgSrc);
it wont work.

Comment: @saorabh, added an update that works fine .. plus some explanation of what was wrong .. hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to pass `imgSrc` through [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent) before using it as a URI component, also, you have an extra whitespace character after the imgSrc, `+' &` should be just `+'&`.

Also your initial selector `.thslider a img` will give you all the `img` tags (including the thumbnails), you may want to restrict that selector to `.nivo-imageLink img`.

Also you are setting the `src` attribute for ALL the images matched by `.thslider .nivo-controlNav a img`, not just the image with the same index number.

Put back together:

```
jQuery(function() { // shortcut for jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.thslider .nivo-imageLink img').each(function (idx) {
     // idx is the index of the image, use the same index for thumbs:
     var $thumb = jQuery(".thslider .nivo-controlNav a img").eq(idx);
     $thumb.attr('src', 'http://saorabh-test1.rtcamp.info/wp-content/themes/twentyten/timthumb.php?src='+ encodeURIComponent(this.src) +'&h=50&w=50&zc=1');
  });
});
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/wzUv5/)

Comment: what you are saying is correct but in my case its not working 
please have a look of this may be it will help you to help me 
http://saorabh-test1.rtcamp.info/
anyway thanks for  helping.